# How can I do to load the static folder from a CSS file?

Tags: python, css, django

How can I do to load the static folder from a CSS file?

I tried to import using `URL()` but it doesn't work. I want to use the static path to give a background to an element.

```css
.input_card:checked+.check-box {
    background: url"{% static 'assets/img/check.png' %}", #458fff;
    }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot ... css files(really any files) rendered from static, will not be proccessed throught the template engine

you could create something like putting your css files in your templates directory
and creating an endpoint like

#### urls.py

```
...
   url("/css/<path:path>",views.render_css),
...
```

### views.py

```
def render_css(request,path):
    return render(request,path,{"some":"vars"})
```

or you can just hardcode the url in style.css and leave it in static